# Laravel streamDownload a pdf file from a guzzle request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have setup the following method using Guzzle and Laravel's `streamDownload()`:

```php
public function export(Request $request, string $uuid) 
{
    $api = $this->do_api;
    $client = new Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->do_token}"]]);
    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($uuid, $api, $client) {
        $client->get("{$api}/customers/my/invoices/{$uuid}/pdf")->getBody();
    },"{$uuid}.pdf");
}
```

And while I have confirmed that this API does return a PDF file, the PDF being returned by laravel has 0 bytes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: either use stream as true, and try to see what you are getting `getBody()->getContents()`, if you are getting raw data, then there are two ways either use sink or convert the raw data to base64 then return it inside object html tag(object does not work in IE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing a `echo` inside the callable function:

```php
$api = $this->do_api;
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->do_token}"]]);
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($uuid, $api, $client) {
    echo $client->get("{$api}/customers/my/invoices/{$uuid}/pdf")->getBody();
},"{$uuid}.pdf");
```